# Google Map API v3 displays only 5 layers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Simple calls with 10 KML files we have only 5 displayed.

It was working for couple months and suddenly stopped (on May28, 2012).

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions);
 ...
 var p1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://domain.com/DLAYYZ.kml");
    p1.setMap(map);
    ....
    var p10 = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://domain.com/A70BR2.kml");
    p10.setMap(map);
 ...

<body onload="initialize()">

  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

If I use Network Links then I'm able to display up to 10 according to limitation
But can not find any limitation for 5 layers.

Also google displays randomly 5 out of 10. Every time I refresh we might have different layers.

Does anyone know if Google restricted something recently?

According this: http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-compare.html only Network Links are restricted to 10.
We have tried from different domain, different api key and still are able to display only 5.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have an enterprise license?  If so, you should request support via the support portal.  http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142858&rd=1

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It is a recently introduced bug, and I've filed a ticket to fix it up.

Comment: This was a bug in the way KML was rendered, and a fix for this rolled out last week.  It seems to work correctly now but please update if there's still an issue.